# What arena will be my chest be, if I promote?

Tags: clash-royale

If I win a match, and thereby go up a level, from what arena will the awarded chest be? From the arena I original started, or the one that I am promoted to?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the chest awarded from a win is based on the Arena played in, not on your personal arena.  If you are a "Visitor" to another arena (which happens most often when you're near the next arena and play one of the lowest ranked opponents in that arena instead of your own) and win, you should receive that arena's chest.

Your Free and Crown Chests are based on your current Arena, though, and the situation where you can visit another Arena is very short-lived if you're actually winning Chests from it, because you'll promote to that Arena in a win or two.

Comment: It is not about being a 'visitor', maybe I should have clarified that more. I was fighting in arena 4, being in arena 4, promoted to arena 5 and awarded an arena 5 chest.

Comment: You are right about the visitor chest. You get the chest you are currently in.

Answer (score 1):

The [Clash Royale official website](https://clashroyale.com/blog/news/chest-rewards-explained) answers this question:

> Chests won from battle are based on the Arena you fought in

So, it does not matter if you got promoted or not, or even what arena you are in. The only factor that decides which chest you get is what arena you fought in for that match.

Answer (score -2):

The awarded chest will be of the arena that you are promoted to. So if you enter a higher arena, you are sure to have at least one chest from that arena.

(Source, personal experience. I went from arena 4 to 5, I was awarded an arena 5 Giant chest, luckily)

Comment: I had a strange experience: I was at 1550 Trophies (Arena 5), decided to play a match and somehow got matched at arena 6. I won the game and got a magical Arena 6 chest. When I went back to the main screen I was still at Arena 5 at 1600 Trophies  but had the Arena 6 Magical chest.

Comment: That's indeed strange. The fact that you played an arena 6 game is probably because the opponent was about to be demoted from 6 (and actually was, because you won), but if you did not reach 1600 trophies, I don't think you should have got that arena 6 chest

Comment: Because when you don't get promoted, the chest comes from the arena you play, and not the arena you see on the home screen.